# How to prevent MYSQL GROUP BY from collapsing NULL values into a single row

Tags: mysql

I have a table such as:

```
table a
+------+-------+
| v1   | v2    |
+------+-------+
|    1 | one   |
|    2 | two   |
|    3 | two   |
|    4 | two   |
|    5 | NULL  |
|    6 | NULL  |
|    7 | three |
|    8 | three |
+------+-------+
```

I want to group the data in this table by the column 'v2'...

```
mysql> select * from a group by v2 order by v1;
+----+-------+
| v1 | v2    |
+----+-------+
|  1 | one   |
|  2 | two   |
|  5 | NULL  |
|  7 | three |
+----+-------+
```

... but leave the NULL values on separate rows. Is it possible to prevent the NULL values from being collapsed into a single row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would accomplish what you're asking:

```
select min(v1) as v1, v2 from a group by v2, ifnull(v2, v1) order by v1;
```

This would group by `v2`, unless it is `NULL`, in which case it would group by `v1`.  Since your two `NULL` values have two different values for `v1`, it would split them apart.

Comment: I need all the `v1`-s that are on the rows with NULL values, but for the other rows it doesn't matter which of the `v1`-s remain. That `table a` comes from another select statement that has LEFT JOIN-s, which produces the NULL-s. (The `v1`-s are ID values...)

Comment: @gregn3 OK, makes sense to me now... I've updated the answer accordingly.